# Accessing an object property from outside scope

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

So I have 4 jsons with that looks like this:

```
{
"group": "A",
"id": "50"
"person": [
  {
        "name": 'Joe',
        "age": '29'
    },
    {
        "name": 'Jessie',
        "age": '27'
    }
 ]
}
```

I used this function to create an array with all the people from 4 different json's files.

```
  list.forEach(list => {
    list.person.forEach(person => {
      peopleArray.push(person);
    });
  })
```

The problem is, when I pick a position from that array, I want to be able to access the group and the ID as well for example:

```
console.log(peopleArray[1].group);
```

Is that possible? Or I would have to those values inside the person?

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Can you show us the function you're using and the data structure of the array?

Comment: I edited the post with the function and an example, I also tried to be more specific, english is still hard to me, sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include those values in the person object

```
const data = {
  group: "A",
  id: "50",
  person: [
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      age: '29'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jessie',
      age: '27'
    }
  ]
}

data.person.map(obj => ({...obj, group: data.group, groupId: data.id}))
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    age: "29",
    group: "A",
    groupId: "50",
    name: "Joe"
  },
  {
    age: "27",
    group: "A",
    groupId: "50",
    name: "Jessie"
  }
]
```

Comment: This end up being the best solution, Thanks!